# Does Python ldap module support LDAP channel binding and LDAP signing

Tags: python, active-directory, ldap, python-ldap

There will be a Microsoft Active Directory update in March 2020 that enables LDAP channel binding and LDAP signing as default, see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4520412/2020-ldap-channel-binding-and-ldap-signing-requirement-for-windows

Will the Python ldap modules still work when LDAP channel binding and LDAP signing is activated to query Active Directory for data?

Do I have to change anything or will it work out of the box?

I connect to Active directory like this:

```py
conn = ldap.initialize('url', bytes_mode=False)
conn.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)
conn.start_tls_s()
conn.simple_bind_s('username', 'password')
```

What is the minimum required Python and ldap module version that I have to use after the update?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using simple bind (like in your code example) then there is no changes needed in your client. It will continue to work with `LdapEnforceChannelBinding=2`.

If you make request signing mandatory (`LDAPServerIntegrity=2`) then you will not be able to use simple bind without ldaps or STARTLS (But your sample code seems to request STARTTLS so it should keep working).

However I haven't tested yet if Pyton-ldap with SASL sets the binding information, it would be relevant if you want to use GSSAPI/Kerberos or SASL/Digest-md5. Both do no longer work with unmodified clients (for example fails with Java sun-ldap JNDI Provider).

Answer (score 3):

I think channel binding does not affect LDAP simple binds over TLS ( LDAPS ).
Channel signing is another thing but is ok too with TLS.

For what i understand is that Channel binding is for CBT tokens and are part of SASL/NTLM for NTLMv2 by example and then not directly implemented by LDAP but by its usage of SASL. From a github project https://github.com/jborean93/ntlm-auth/blob/master/README.md i can find CBT defined as some value derived from server certificate, i guess it might be covered by rfc 5929, and channel binding token is defined within chapter 4 'tls-server-end-point' Channel Binding Type.

This is the same for GSSAPI/Kerberos ( see https://github.com/requests/requests-kerberos/blob/master/requests_kerberos/kerberos_.py _get_channel_bindings_application_data )

I didn't looked about SASL/Digest-md5 CBT though.

Channel binding is CBT : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4034879/how-to-add-the-ldapenforcechannelbinding-registry-entry